# Is Deno's dynamic import() implementation conformant with ECMA-262?

Tags: javascript, deno

Specification:

- [13.3.10.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-import-call-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
- [13.3.10.1.1 ContinueDynamicImport ( promiseCapability, moduleCompletion )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-ContinueDynamicImport)

When using dynamic `import()` in Deno there is a strange behaviour that is exclusive to Deno: bare string specifiers don't dynamically import the module and can be fashioned to consistently throw, see [Deno dynamic import("./exports") throws module not found for "exports.js" dynamically created in the script](https://gist.github.com/guest271314/4637bb1288321256d7c14c72ebc81137).

After some research I located this [Dynamic import module is not found when created after the application started. #20945](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/20945) which while still open is marked as `working as designed` per [Do not permission prompt for statically analyzable dynamic imports](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/17697#issuecomment-1486509016).

In the linked blog post https://deno.com/blog/v1.33#fewer-permission-checks-for-dynamic-imports we read

> Keep in mind that permissions will still be checked for dynamic imports that are not statically analyzable (ie. don’t use string literals for the specifier):

```
import("" + "https://deno.land/std/version.ts");

import(`https://deno.land/std@${STD_VERSION}/version.ts`);

const someVariable = "./my_mod.ts";
import(someVariable);
```

This means we have to employ special treatment for ECMA-262 dynamic `import()` in Deno.

So, let's test with a variable that is not a raw string that satisfies that Deno-specific special treatment of specifiers when using `import()` and see what happens

```
// test_dynamic_module.js

import { exists } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts";

const [...modules] = Deno.args;

console.log({ modules });

if (await exists("node_modules")) {
  await Deno.remove("node_modules", {recursive: true});
}

for (const module of modules) {
  try {
    await import(module);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

```
deno run -A test_dynamic_import.js npm:zod
{ modules: [ "npm:zod" ] }
TypeError: Loading unprepared module: npm:zod, imported from: file:///home/user/test_dynamic_import.js
    at async file:///home/user/test_dynamic_import.js:15:5 {
  code: "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND"
}
```

We get `TypeError: Loading unprepared module`.

But why should a *dynamic* `import()` have to be *prepared*?

If we use static `import` things work as intended.

To me this is a bug that is asserted to be working as designed though effectively means dynamic `import()` in Deno is not dynamic at all.

Is Deno's dynamic `import()` implementation conformant with ECMA-262?

-

To avoid speculation about what is going on here, we create the file `exports.js` on the local file system  within the script [dynamic_import_always_throws.js](https://gist.github.com/guest271314/4637bb1288321256d7c14c72ebc81137#file-dynamic_import_always_throws-js-L27)   and test the same code using `node`, `bun`, and `deno`.

The file exists.

Only `deno` throws in this case of the raw string specifier.

`deno` consistently throws `TypeError: Loading unprepared module code: ... "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND"` when the raw string specifier `./exports.js` is used here `const { default: module } = await import("./exports.js"); // Raw string specifier`

```
// Deno dynamic import("./exports") throws module not found for "exports.js" dynamically created in the script
// dynamic_import_always_throws.js
// References: https://www.reddit.com/r/Deno/comments/18unb03/comment/kfsszsw/ https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/20945
// Usage:
// deno run -A dynamic_import_always_throws.js
// bun run dynamic_import_always_throws.js
// node --experimental-default-type=module dynamic_import_always_throws.js
import { open, unlink } from "node:fs/promises";
const runtime = navigator.userAgent;
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
try {
  const script = `export default 1;`;
  // deno
  if (runtime.includes("Deno")) {
    await Deno.writeFile("exports.js", encoder.encode(script));
  }
  // node
  if (runtime.includes("Node")) {
    const dynamic = await open("./exports.js", "w");
    await dynamic.write(script);
    await dynamic.close();
  }
  // bun
  if (runtime.includes("Bun")) {
    await Bun.write("exports.js", encoder.encode(script));
  }
  const { default: module } = await import("./exports.js"); // Raw string specifier
  console.log({ module });
  console.log({ runtime });
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Deno always throws.");
  console.log({ runtime });
  console.trace();
  console.log(e.stack);
} finally {
  console.log("Finally");
  // node, bun
  if (runtime.includes("Node") || runtime.includes("Bun")) {
    await unlink("./exports.js");
  } // deno
  else if (runtime.includes("Deno")) {
    await Deno.remove("./exports.js");
  }
}
```

Comment: "*Is Deno's dynamic `import()` implementation conformant with ECMA-262?*" - yes of course, the runtime is responsible for module specifier resolution and module loading. It can throw whenever it wants. ECMAScript does not govern anything about this.

Comment: @Bergi Interesting. That means `deno` has completely different behaviour for `import("./bare-string-specifier.js")` than `node`, `bun`, `tjs`, `qjs` and each are conformant with ECMA-262. Kindly post your comment as an answer.

Comment: You seem to already have read the specification yourself. Why did you come to a different (or no) conclusion? I can't really answer without understanding what you missed.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where using a bare string specifier should throw in the steps. AFAICT `deno` is the only JavaScript runtime that has that behaviour. I suspect the decision has something to do with TypeScript part of `deno`, doesn't matter though what the reason is, my question is is the behaviour conformant with ECMA-262, or not. Throwing and not throwing for bare string specifiers doesn't appear to me to be consistent behaviour that would qualify both as equally conformant with the specification.

Comment: It doesn't `throw`, it rejects the promise. In the very part of the specification you already linked. And I don't see where the spec distinguishes bare string specifiers anyway?

Comment: @Bergi _"It doesn't `throw`, it rejects the promise._" ? With an error: `"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND"`. What this means is that we can't run the same code `import("./bare-string-specifier.js")` in multiple JavaScript runtimes and expect the same result, thus efforts such as Winter CG have to get past this. I have never before encountered a specification section where both throwing and not throwing for the same input are optional; arbitrary and at the discretion of the implementation.

Comment: @Bergi _"And I don't see where the spec distinguishes bare string specifiers anyway?"_ So given your interpretation of the specification `import()` can be rejected for any arbitrary reason per _"7. IfAbruptRejectPromise(specifierString, promiseCapability)."_ and still be in conformance with ECMA-262?

Comment: No, that rejects the promise when `ToString` fails, which is not arbitrary. I was talking about `ContinueDynamicImport`, where the promise can be rejected with an error that is at the discretion of the implementation. The implementation algorithm won't be arbitrary either, although some implementations will have non-deterministic parts in their algorithm like loading a module source over the network. (Browsers do that, for example, and there's nothing wrong with it, and no reason to assume it would violate the specification).

Comment: _"No, that rejects the promise when ToString fails,"_ `ToString` shouldn't fail in this case. Why would it? I have a reason to think the implementation violates the specification. No other JavaScript runtime does that for raw string specifiers. `bun` supports TypeScript and doesn't have to do that. Anyway, I think your comments should be in an anwer. Mod-squad is liable to delete at least my comments here at any time. It took a while to figure out what `deno` was doing in this case in some code I was running using a dynamic import.

Comment: `ToString` can fail when you do `import({toString() { throw new Error; }})` or something like that. That doesn't seem relevant to your question though.

Comment: Neither the specification nor other runtimes prescribe what deno has to do with any specifier.

Comment: Btw you still haven't explained what you mean by "bare string specifiers" or "raw string specifiers".

Comment: _"Btw you still haven't explained what you mean by "bare string specifiers" or "raw string specifiers""_ Sure I did. In my first reply to you. This throws `import("./bare-string-specifier.js")` in `deno` where the file is created in the  file executed. Clearly you have not run the linked `.js` file in the gist I wrote https://gist.github.com/guest271314/4637bb1288321256d7c14c72ebc81137#file-dynamic_import_always_throws-js-L27. I can make that code throw consistently, ad infinitum, using `const { default: module } = await import("./exports.js")`. You are expecting that behaviour for that case?

Comment: @Bergi I updated the original post to include the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by "bare / raw string specifier". As opposed to what? You are always supposed to pass a string as the specifier to dynamic `import`.

Comment: "*The file exists.*" - so what? Deno is free to not resolve it as a module based on whatever criteria - it might be a whitelist, a blacklist, a security profile, a package.json file, or the fact that it didn't exist in the filesystem when the program was started. There is no inconsistency or spec violation here. Sure other runtimes may behave differently, and again, that's fine. There would only be an inconsistency if you did a normal `import` and a dynamic import, or multiple dynamic imports, of the same specifier, and the first did resolve to the module but that later would fail.

Comment: @Bergi _"it might be a whitelist, a blacklist,"_ There are no such things as "whitelist" or "blacklist". Colors have nothing to do with allow list and deny list. _"There would only be an inconsistency if you did a normal import and a dynamic import, or multiple dynamic imports, of the same specifier, and the first did resolve to the module but that later would fail."_ That makes no sense. There is inconsistency, just your criteria in opposite order. If we don't remove the file the Nth dynamic `import()` works. Good to know ECMA-262 section on `import()` is essentially useless re specifiers.

Comment: "*If we don't remove the file the Nth dynamic `import()` works*" - what do you mean by Nth? There is only a single `import("./exports.js")` in the example you've posted.

Comment: Read the script. Run the script. Check out what's going on.  We dynamically create the file `exports.js` in `dynamic_import_always_throws.js` use dynamic `import()` when the file exists. Then we remove the script in `finally`. If we don't remove the file that exists on the machine the Nth run of the script imports the file. Now, we can also do something like `import("" + "./exports.s")` and `const dynamic = "./exports.js"; await import(dynamic)` - which Deno suggests using in their blog, etc. - and the 1st `import()` will not throw. A raw string specifier should work. This is wild behaviour.

Comment: Oh, you mean multiple runs of the entire program. But again, nothing wrong with a program behaving different under different initial conditions. It seems deno is deterministic, and the behaviour is desired and documented! The only thing that would potentially be a spec violation is if both `import("./exports.js")` and `import("./exp" + "orts.js")` were to be executed in the same module during the same run of the program and did resolve to different modules.

Comment: I didn't try that. I just happended to encounter this issue while running the same code in `node`, `bun`, and `deno`. I had no idea that Deno was doing that on purpose. Even Deno folks have filed issues re the matter - after forgetting they had implemented dynamic `import()` in a non-dynamic way [Dynamic import module is not found when created after the application started. #20945](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/20945). What this means is dynamic `import()` in `deno` is decidely _not_ dynamic. No JavaScript programmer should expect dynamic `import()` to be dynamic when using `deno`.

Comment: This `const { default: moduleA0 } = await import("./exp" + "orts.js")` only works when this `const { default: moduleA1 } = await import("./exports.js"); // Raw string specifier` is not in the same script. So even Deno's suggested usage doesn't work in some cases.  ECMA-262 evidently doesn't specify this one way or the other, per you. Either way this is decidedly non-dynamic behaviour.